# What is the best way to Realm migrate a field from one class to another?

Tags: kotlin, realm, realm-migration

I have a Realm class `A` containing a Realm class `B` with a 1 to 1 relationship.
I've had enough of this and want to put all the `B` fields and content in class `A`.

What would be the easiest way to make the migration?
I need to tranfer the existing values from `B` to their `A` counterpart.

I'm working with Kotlin on the Realm Java SDK.

Comment: A migration is designed to allow changes to be made objects properties as the app develops over time. This sounds like it's a one-off situation where you're doing it once and never again. If that's the case, is the app in production or still in development? If you are simply adding new properties to an existing object, that's an additive change and no migration is necessary. You could just read the properties of Object B and assign then to Object A's new properties. If there's more to it, can you update the question for clarity?